# Why is this hover toggle jQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have separate jQuery functions for "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" that work fine:

```
$('#imgPostTravel').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#imgPostTravel').addClass('popout_image');
    $('#imgPostTravel').addClass('shadow');
});

$('#imgPostTravel').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#imgPostTravel').removeClass('popout_image');
    $('#imgPostTravel').removeClass('shadow');
});
```

...but am hoping to consolidate it into one "hover" toggle operation.

I first want to make sure it really works, so tried the following on a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/n9sq7x8y/2/):

```
$( "ptVerbiage" ).hover(function() {
    $(this).val('yep!');
}, function() {
    $(this).val('nope!');
});
```

I've tried several things besides setting the value of "val" (changing the "disabled" attr, changing the color, backgroundcolor, etc.) but none of them does a thing. Is this the wrong way to hover/toggle, or what's wrong?

Comment: jQuery has a [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function.

Comment: `ptVerbiage` != `#ptVerbiage`

Comment: the `ptVerbiage` element doesn't have a value attribute. to change the text you need to use `.text()`: http://jsfiddle.net/n9sq7x8y/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing a #

`$("ptVerbiage")` => `$("#ptVerbiage")`

AND

not `.val()` but `.text()`; as .val is for inputs

should look like this

```
$( "#ptVerbiage" ).hover(function() {
  $(this).text('yep!');
}, function() {
  $(this).text('nope!');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n9sq7x8y/4/

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the hashtag to make reference to an ID. Also, your target element is a `h2`, that has no `.val()` method because it is not a form (text) input. You have to use `.text()` instead.

The portion of code should look like this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/n9sq7x8y/3/)):

```
$("#ptVerbiage").hover(function() {
    $(this).text('yep!');
}, function() {
    $(this).text('nope!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using everyone's suggestions, this is what works:

```
$( "#imgPostTravel" ).hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('popout_image');
    $(this).addClass('shadow');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('popout_image');
    $(this).removeClass('shadow');
});
```